# Some questions on dendrogram - python (Scipy)

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis, dendrogram

I am new to scipy but I managed to get the expected dendrogram. I am some more questions;

1. In the dendrogram, distance between some points are `0` but its not
   visible due to image border. How can I remove the border and make
   the lower limit of y-axis to `-1`, so that it is clearly visible.
   e.g. distance between these points are `0` (13,17), (2,10), (4,8,19)
2. How can I prune/truncate on a particular distance. for e.g. prune at `0.4`
3. How to write these clusters(after pruning) to a file

My python code:

```
import scipy
import pylab
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch
import numpy as np

D = np.genfromtxt('LtoR.txt', dtype=None)
def llf(id):
    return str(id)
fig = pylab.figure(figsize=(10,10))
Y = sch.linkage(D, method='single')
Z1 = sch.dendrogram(Y,leaf_label_func=llf,leaf_rotation=90)
fig.show()
fig.savefig('dendrogram.png')
```

Dendrogram:
[image]

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1.`fig.gca().set_ylim(-0.4,1.2)` Here `gca()` returns the current `axes` object, so you can give it a name

```
ax=fig.gca()
ax.set_ylim(-0.4,ax.get_ylim()[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

2. You can prune the dendrogram and obtain your clusters using [fcluster](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster.html).
   To prune at a distance of 0.4:

   `clusters = sch.fcluster(Y,t = 0.4,criterion = 'distance')`
3. The resulting array (`clusters`) contains the cluster label for every observation in your data. You can write the array using [numpy.savetxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html):

   `np.savetxt('clusters.txt', clusters, delimiter=',')`

Answer (score 0):

The border is shown because of the axis. So you can remove the border using the following command:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.3, 0.71, 0.6, 0.2])
Y = sch.linkage(D, method='ward')
Z2 = sch.dendrogram(Y)
ax2.set_xticks([])
ax2.set_yticks([])
ax2.axis('off')
```

`ax.axis('off')` hides the border.